# How to check if a yield has been triggered within a method?

Tags: python, generator, yield

In the below method, if a certain condition is met, I'm using `yield` to return a generator. Within that same method, I'd like to **check if the `yield` has already been triggered** (thus the generator populated).

I've read that `next(generator)` is the common way to check if a generator is empty. But I don't see how I could apply that in this situation where **the check has to happened within the method itself**.

Here's the snippet :

```
def my_method(my_list: list) -> List[Iterable]:

    for el in my_list:

        if el == "foo": 
            yield el        

        if <yield_has_been_triggered> and el == "bar":
            break
```

My current non-elegant solution is :

```
def my_method(my_list: list) -> List[Iterable]:

    check = False

    for el in my_list:

        if el == "foo":
            check = True
            yield el            

        if check and el == "bar":       
            break
```

Is there a solution to get this **<yield_has_been_triggered>** information ?

Comment: No offence, but I suggest going through a tutorial or documentation on generators again. You have all the concepts wrong. `yield` does not return a generator. Your function does not return `List[Iterable]`. A generator is not "empty" or "populated". It just generates.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd probably look at doing that where you actually called the generator tbh:

```
called = False
for item in my_method(<list>);
    if called and item == "bar": 
        break
    called = True

    ...
```

But otherwise, pretty much how you've done it I think.

```
In [3]: def myfunc():
   ...:     _called = False
   ...:     for i in range(10):
   ...:         if _called and i == 5:
   ...:             break
   ...:         _called = True
   ...:         yield i
   ...:

In [4]: for i in myfunc():
   ...:     print(i)
   ...:
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Good point. Checking it on the outside seems the most elegant. But it may break the contract of that function. I.e. if it is yielding more than its documentation says it should be, then it is simply wrong. Telling the users of the function to put `if called and item == "bar": break` around it may be completely wrong.